# Jquery eq selector with variable does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, selector, equals

My javascript/jquery code

```
var galcont = $("#content div.lt2");
$(galcont":eq(0)").css("opacity","0.5");
```

**Does not work**

But

```
$("#content div.lt2:eq(0)").css("opacity","0.5");
```

Does work..

What is wrong with my syntax? Why can I not use a variable selector with :eq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `galcont` is a jQuery object, and not a string... possible correct solutions:

```
var galcont = $("#content div.lt2");
galcont.eq(0).css("opacity","0.5");
```

or with strings concating

```
var galcont = "#content div.lt2";
$(galcont + ":eq(0)").css("opacity","0.5");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
var galcont = $("#content div.lt2");
$(galcont).eq(0).css("opacity","0.5");
```

Or:

```
var galcont = $("#content div.lt2");
$(galcont).find(':eq(0)').css("opacity","0.5");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
galcont.eq(0).css("opacity","0.5");
```

The reason why you can't just do "$(galcont":eq(0)")" is because galcont is no longer a string, but a jquery object

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var galcont = "#content div.lt2";

$(galcont +":eq(0)").css("opacity","0.5");
```